Wearing functional cufflinks on Shabbos
This question might be a duplicate of
Wearing Watches on Shabbat
but my question is on other types of functional wearable items that may be considered Tachshitim.
What is the determining factor that determines if one may wear cufflinks on Shabbos that may also have a prohibited use?
For example, cufflinks that have a functionally working compass or a thermometer which can measure temperature.
Additionally, can one read the thermometer or angle their wrist for the compass to spin?
Pictured left-to-right are a clock, compass, & thermometer cufflinks:

To my understanding, these cufflinks should be considered as Tachshitim, with their secondary use being useful measuring devices.
And they should still be allowed to be worn on Shabbos if they were to break, so long as the person would still wear them.

A wristwatch is worn on the skin. A whole generation was raised on the Shemiras Shabbos Kehilchasa's view that it has to be pretty and gold ... but Rav Moshe Feinstein zt"l allowed any wristwatch. (But not a pocketwatch, and back in the day he was worried that wearing wristwatches would lead to wearing pocketwatches.) Here the cufflink isn't just a decoration, it's actually keeping your shirt closed.

Didn't GI Joe have laser-shooting ones too? :)
